# How can I continue an 'if' statement to compare multiple function return values as parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function that tries to determine whether the result of one function is true, and the result of a second function is also true.

```
function foo() {
    var result = false;
    if (/*condition is true*/) result = true;
    return result;
}
function bar() {
    var result = false;
    if (/*condition is true*/) result = true;
    return result;
}
if (foo() && bar()) {
    // Both are true
}
```

My problem is that if the first function returns false, it doesn't continue the 'if' statement and call the second function or compare them.
How can I get the 'if' statement to continue even if the first function call returns false?

Comment: use `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript will short-circuit an `if` as soon as the result is known and not evaluate the rest of the terms.  You could do this instead if you want to guarantee that both `foo()` and `bar()` are always called:

```
var fooResult = foo();
var barResult = bar();
if (fooResult && barResult) {
    // Both are true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, as well as telling me why the issue was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&&` and it will not execute the second condition if the first condition fails.

If you want to execute both the functions still then execute the functions first and store the result in a variable and then compare them.

```
function foo() {
    var result = false;
    if (/*condition is true*/) result = true;
    return result;
}
function bar() {
    var result = false;
    if (/*condition is true*/) result = true;
    return result;
}

var firstResult = foo(),
   secondResult = bar();

   if(firstResult && secondResult) {

   }
```

Comment: You've changed the logic which I don't think is what the OP wanted.  They want to keep the same logic, but just make sure that both `foo()` and `bar()` are always called.

Comment: @mohamedrias If I used `||` then it would check to see if either foo() OR bar() returned true, meaning if only one of them returned true it would carry on.

Comment: Oh then @jfriend00 has proposed the correct answer :)

Comment: @JosephWebber One doubt, why would you want to execute the second function in any case if the first condition fails? It's meaningless to execute the second function

Comment: @mohamedrias In my script, foo() is checking if all dropdowns are the default option, and bar() is checking if any textboxes are empty. So when I try to submit my form, I need to make sure both the dropdowns are not default and textboxes are not empty.

Comment: Great. If any one of them fails also you are going to throw some error and avoid form submission? May be you want to show different error messages i suppose.

Comment: @mohamedrias I've already handled individual error messages for each dropdown and textbox, and the form is only submitted if both conditions are true. =) Of course, there's also server-side validation to re-check the data in case some naughty person tries anything funny like SQL injections or data manipulation.

Comment: In that case, I really don't see any benefit of executing the second function if the first one fails :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option to do that is:

```
if (foo() & bar()) {
    // Both are true
  }
```

Just place single & instead two &&. Short circuit AND (&&) never evaluate second argument of if-statement if first argument is false. But Logical AND (&) will evaluate the second argument even if the first argument is false.